# CakePHP 2.1 create select box

Tags: cakephp, drop-down-menu, cakephp-2.1

I am trying to add below style..

```
<div class="rowElem noborder">
        <label>Language:</label>
        <div class="formRight noSearch">
          <select name="select2" class="chzn-select">
            <option value="opt1">Choose the Language</option>
            <option value="opt2" selected="selected">Kannada</option>
            <option value="opt3">Telugu</option>
            <option value="opt4">Tamil</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="fix"></div>
</div>
```

But in cakephp, I have this code

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('language_id', array('class' => 'chzn-select' )); ?>
```

Please give me the solution..

Comment: The solution to what? What does the CakePHP helper code produce?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are asking, this is what you need to do.

In your controller you will create your options array for the select box:

```
$this->set('languageOptions', array('opt1' => 'Choose Language', 'opt2' => 'Kannada', 'opt3' => 'Telugu', 'opt4' => 'Tamil'));
```

Then in the view, you create the form:

```
<div class="rowElem noborder">
    <label for="language_id">Language:</label>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('language_id', array('class' => 'chzn-select', 'options' => $languageOptions, 'label' => false, 'div' => array('class' => 'formRight noSearch'))); ?>
    <div class="fix"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$langs = array('opt1' => 'Choose Language', 'opt2' => 'Kannada', 'opt3' => 'Telugu', 'opt4' => 'Tamil');

$this->set(compact('langs')); // if you set options from controller
```

Then in view try this:

```
$this->Form->input('language_id', array(
                                      'type' => 'select',
                                      'options' => $langs,
                                      'selected' => 2 // suppose default select Kannada
                                  )
                  );
```

Answer (score -2):

Cake Php Select Option Code

Language:
    Form->input('language_id', array('class' => 'chzn-select', 'options' => $languageOptions, 'label' => false, 'div' => array('class' => 'formRight noSearch'))); ?>